# regex match special case

Tags: python, regex

I have a cinematic scenario with a bunch of strings like this:

```
80101_intertitle:Blablabla
80101_1:BlablablaBlablabla
80101_2:Blablabla
80101_:BlablablaBlablablaBlablabla
80101_3:BlablablaBlablabla
80101_11:Blablabla
801_1:Blablabla
801_2:Blablabla
```

And my goal is to match all the numbers up to `:` in selected sequence (selected is `80101_` in this example, strings #2, #3, #5, #6), matching strings without existing numbers (like `80101_:Blablab`, string #4) but without matching the string with `_intertitle` (string #1).

My current regex looks like this (code in Python):

```
selection = "80101"; # I'm getting this from elsewhere
pattern = selection + "_" + "\d*";
```

This matches all the strings with/without numbers but also a string with `_intertitle`. If I modify my pattern like this `"\d[^:]*"`, it doesn't match `_intertitle` but also doesn't match the string without numbers... I can't get the right pattern, could anyone please lead me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: So what about `pattern = selection + "_" + "\d*:";`

Comment: post the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add "(?=:)" in the and of your pattern:

```
r"80101_\d*(?=:)"
```

This means: select "80101_" + zero or more digits only if it’s followed by ":". In case of "80101_intertitle:Blablabla" we have a non-digit symbol between "80101_" and ":", so it doesn't match.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative lookahead:

```
80101_\d*(?!intertitle)
```

That negative lookahead `(?! ... )` prevents a match if its contents are present at the point it is used.

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y7sPRm/1)

Your pattern could be written as:

```
pattern = selection + r"_\d*(?!intertitle)"
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to exclude `intertitle` but I was wrong with a syntax..! suit suggested the solution with `\d*(?=:)`, I guess it'll be more genera

Answer (score 0):

You need anchors and multiline flag. Also, you should add the `:.*` at the end of the regex as well to match the whole string.

```
^80101_\d*:.*$
```

See the Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yqGgrv/1

Here is the respective python code as well:

```
In [1]: s = """80101_intertitle:Blablabla
   ...: 80101_1:BlablablaBlablabla
   ...: 80101_2:Blablabla
   ...: 80101_:BlablablaBlablablaBlablabla
   ...: 80101_3:BlablablaBlablabla
   ...: 80101_11:Blablabla
   ...: 801_1:Blablabla
   ...: 801_2:Blablabla"""

In [2]: import re
In [4]: re.findall(r'^80101_\d*:.*$', s, re.M)
Out[4]: 
['80101_1:BlablablaBlablabla',
 '80101_2:Blablabla',
 '80101_:BlablablaBlablablaBlablabla',
 '80101_3:BlablablaBlablabla',
 '80101_11:Blablabla']
```

Comment: Sorry my explanation wasn't clear enough! I didn't want the whole string, just the part up to `:`. The regex I was looking for was like `\d*(?=:)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is easily done:

```
import re

s = '''80101_intertitle:Blablabla
80101_1:BlablablaBlablabla
80101_2:Blablabla
80101_:BlablablaBlablablaBlablabla
80101_3:BlablablaBlablabla
80101_11:Blablabla
801_1:Blablabla
801_2:Blablabla'''

matches = re.findall(r'(80101_\d+:.*)', s)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
matches = re.findall(r'(80101_:.*)', s)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```